# error de sintaxis c++

Tags: c++

hola amigos soy nuevo aqui quiero que me ayuden en este programa estoy usando un textbox . resulta ser que la informacion quiero guardarla en un archivo texto pero que el usuario le pomga nombre al archivo texto creo que la forma que lo guardo esta mala

```
void admpacientes()
{

char nfichero[50];
gotoxy(4,5);printf("ADMINISTRACION DEL PACIENTE");

gotoxy(1,8);printf("NOMBRE:");
textbox nombre(8,8,20,19);
nombre.Mostrar();
nombre.Capturar();

gotoxy(1,11);printf("APELLIDO:");
textbox apellido(10,11,20,19);
apellido.Mostrar();
apellido.Capturar();

gotoxy(35,11);printf("EDAD:");
textbox edad(40,11,5,5);
edad.Mostrar();
edad.Capturar();

gotoxy(1,15);printf("DIRECCION:");
textbox direccion(11,15,35,30);
direccion.Mostrar();
direccion.Capturar();

gotoxy(50,15);printf("CELULAR:");
textbox cel(58,15,15,13);
cel.Mostrar();
cel.Capturar();

gotoxy(1,19);printf("REGION:");
textbox rg(10,19,15,13);
rg.Mostrar();
rg.Capturar();

gotoxy(35,19);printf("PAIS:");
textbox pais(40,19,15,13);
pais.Mostrar();
pais.Capturar();

gotoxy(1,22);printf("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO DONDE DESEA GUARDAR LA INFORMACION DEL PACIENTE: ");
    scanf("%s",&nfichero);


 FILE *archivo;

archivo=fopen("nfichero.txt","w"); //para escritura

fprintf(archivo,"%s\n%s\n,%d\n,%s\n,%d\n,%s\n,%s\n",nombre.Texto(),apellido.Texto(),edad.Texto(),direccion.Texto(),cel.Texto(),rg.Texto(),pais.Texto());

fclose(archivo);

getch();
system("CLS");
}//fin depantalla administrador de pacientes
```

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo con la extension (.txt): ");
scanf("%s",&nfichero); //Aqui el usuario ingresa ejemplo.txt
FILE *archivo = fopen(nfichero,"w"); //Aqui se le da el nombre almacenado en nfichero
```

Lo que estas haciendo es darle el nombre `"nfichero.txt"` directamente, cuando lo que quieres hacer es darle el nombre **almacenado** en `nfichero`. Por eso debes enviarlo como parametro a la hora de usar la funcion `FILE * fopen (const char *filename, const char *opentype)`.